# Is It Possible To Store Background Colour Hex Then Display Using That Colour?

Tags: php, colors

I have a form that allows users to create a design for the back of a card. Users enter the title, their name and upload a small image. This is then displayed back and looks like a large playing card with a small image in the middle and the text above and below. The background colour of the card is set in the css and cannot be changed by the user. I would like users to be able to enter their background colour in hex then display this back with the image and text. How would this be done? Which procedures would I need to look at?

[image: http://thetradingcardgenerator.com/images/Predators_Back.png![How To Store Background Colour?][1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user select the color, you should store it into the database and the, When you want to show the card, do something like this:

```
<div style="background: <?php echo $bgcolor?>"> <!-- here is the BGCOLOR selected by the user -->
  <div>Trading card text</div>
  <div><img src="/img/the_image.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

that's it

Answer (score 0):

When you saving small_image and text in database then you can store one more data `bgcolor`
Suppose we have these data stored in database

```
$data['small_image'] = "logo.png";
$data['bgcolor'] = "#00FF00";
```

Your code should be like this:

```
<div class="tradingcard" style="background:<?=$data['bgcolor']?>">
 <div>Trading card text</div>
 <div><img src="<?=$data['small_image']?>"></div>
</div>
```

You can check it [Online demo](http://goo.gl/wXy7ay)

You page will looks like this
[image: Output of this code]

Comment: Thank you. I will try this tomorrow and post back if I have any problems.